# In C++ how to convert a string to class object?

Tags: c++, objective-c

For example i have a class named "WaterScene", in the .xml i have saved as string "WaterScene" when i read the .xml i have to convert that string to class. One approach is just string comparison

```
if( string == "WaterScene")
return new WaterScene;
```

Is there any generic way to do this to avoid string comparison? Like in objective C(dynamic language) we can get the class using string...

```
Class classObject =[[NSBundle mainBundle] classNamed:string];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [Generic Class factory](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=6784) to solve the issue... First i am registering class and storing it in a map before main().

Answer (score 7):

If all of the objects you would be returning are derived from a common base class, you could use a `std::map<std::string,BaseClass *>`.  The comparisons ultimately in there somewhere, but it keeps things better organized.

Comment: Another alternative is to store pointers to creation functions inside the `std::map`.

Comment: @Chandan My apologies, I forgot that self-accepted answers aren't at the top!  Glad it worked.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't do it with standard C++. C++ has no notion of [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29). Sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you could probably use an implementation that leverages the [Abstract Factory Pattern](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). Here is a pretty good article on a [Boost centric implementation](http://arcticinteractive.com/2008/10/06/boost-centric-factory-pattern-implementation/).

Answer (score 0):

No. At some level, a string comparison must be done in your code. C++ doesn't have any mechanism for that kind of dynamic programming.

Answer (score 0):

No. But to elegantly get around this limitation I would enumerate all possible classes and create an array of corresponding class names:

```
enum ECLASSTYPE
{
  CT_WATER_SCENE,
  CT_SOME_OTHER,
  CT__MAX,
};

static const string g_classNames[CT__MAX] =
{
  "WaterScene", // CT_WATER_SCENE
  "SomeOther", // CT_SOME_OTHER
};
```

When parsing xml, decode the string name to enum and pass it to the factory method:

```
switch (classType)
{
  case CT_WATER_SCENE:
  {
    result = new WaterScene();
    break;
  }
  ...
}
```